# Show the selected value of the dropdown after reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I am working on this from a very long time. I want to show the elements of a collection in a drop down, and on click of a value I must reload the page and display its details. This I am able to do easily. The problem is, When the page is reloaded, the selected value of the dropdown is getting reset. So I just want retain the selected value after the reload to use ':selected' attribute so that after relaod the clicked value is shown. So please let me know how to fix this issue ASAP. Pls Help me out with this.

```
    <%= form_tag({},:method => :get, :class => 'formSearch absolute') do %>
     <%=select("post", "id", @other_schools.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank =>    true }, :onchange => "this.form.submit();") %>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: you have option of selecetd may be pasting code snippet help more

Comment: Pls Go through the question. I have added the code to it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code,
You are searching based on select box value and you want to populate search option

I will use `select_tag`more info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

`<%=select_tag("post_id", options_for_colletcion_select(@other_schools,p.name, p.id ,params[:post_id), { :include_blank =>    true }, :onchange => "this.form.submit();") %>`

You can go through docs for syntax options.

Answer (score 0):

In this code where does the `this.form.submit();` method will go?

```
<%=select_tag("post_id", options_for_colletcion_select(@other_schools,p.name, p.id ,params[:post_id), { :include_blank => true }, :onchange => "this.form.submit();") %>
```